# Inserting an image attribute in a database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I want to insert in a database some value when i click an image but something is going wrong.
Here is my code:
I edited my post. I made the changes that you suggested but still nothing happens when I click an image.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
      body{background-color:black; background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute;width:100%;}
      img.imgnavbar{height:auto; width:15%; opacity: 1.0; padding:2%; z-index:100;}
      .menu{padding-top:3%;width:100%;}   
      img.shadow{height:100%; width:100%; bottom:0px; position:fixed; left:0%; z-index:-2;}

</style>

<script>
$(".imgnavbar").click(function() {
   var $myimage=$(this);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'submit_form.php',
       data: { 'img_alt': $myimage.attr('alt') },
       success: function(){
          console.log("OK!");
       }
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div  align="center" class="menu">
<img  src='images/green.png' id="green" alt="green" class="imgnavbar"/>
<img  src='images/blue.png' id="blue" alt="blue" class="imgnavbar"/>
<img  src='images/orange.png' id="orange" alt="orange" class="imgnavbar"/>
<img  src='images/red.png' id="red" alt="red" class="imgnavbar"/>
</div>
<img  src='images/shadow.png' id="shadow" class="shadow"/>
</body>

</html>
```

and the php:

```
<?php

    include ("db.php");

    $myimage        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['img_alt']));

    $addCompany  = "INSERT INTO company (id,name) VALUES ('','$myimage')";
    mysql_query($addCompany) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Could you please help me with some advices? Thanks!

Comment: Although not illegal per se, in general it's bad practice to have multiple distinct elements with the same value for the `id` attribute.

Comment: Won't that click event only work for the first image with it using IDs? Someone correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Not illegal, but in this case it will prevent the code from working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the class attribute, you can't use the id attr twice.

```
<script>
**$(".imgnavbar")**.click(function() {
   var $myimage=$(this);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'submit_form.php',
       data: { 'img_alt': $myimage.attr('alt') },
       success: function(){
          console.log("OK!");
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 In combination with my answer, this should solve the most obvious problems.

Answer (score 4):

You are using different names for your sent in variable:

```
data: { 'img_alt': $myimage.attr('alt') },
```

but in php you use:

```
$myimage        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['myimage']));
```

Change that to:

```
$myimage        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['img_alt']));
```

Also note that your code is vulnerable to sql injection. You should switch to PDO / mysqli and prepared statements with bound variables.

Comment: @user1820705 And check Joe's answer, with the current code only the first element will be click-able.

Comment: Thanks for help, I made the changes but still nothing happens when I click a photo. Could you please look a little over my code now?

Comment: @user1820705 Is the php file called? If so, do some basic debugging there like a `var_dump($myimage)` and check the result in the network tab of the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are accessing the wrong $_POST parameter

Also all your image elements have the same ID. This is probably not a good idea. Perhaps try using the class as the handle. Also, why not try debugging the app to get some more meaningful error information. You can print out the response from the AJAX post as so:

```
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

Then try var_dump($_POST) in your PHP to see what is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly: Each id attribute can only be used once per page. You must not have the same id attribute for different elements